# select * WHERE status <> 'deleted' OR status <> 'completed' AND update_datetime < unix_timestamp(now() - interval 7 day)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I would like to pull all rows where the status column IS NOT marked 'deleted' AND where the status is marked 'completed' if the update_datetime column is older than 7 days (MySQL version 2013-04-11 11:22:44 ).

Here's my feeble and failed attempt:

```
WHERE
    status <> 'deleted'
 OR status <> 'completed'
AND update_datetime < unix_timestamp( now() - interval 7 day )
```

Comment: Remember that parentheses are your friends.

Comment: I make it a rule to never use OR and AND in the same where clause without parentheses even if the result would follow the order of operations because the guy maintaining it a year later won't know what you intended.

Comment: When the `update_datetime` value is not older than 7 days, what should the `status` value be? Just any or necessarily *not* `'completed'` (as long as it is not `'deleted'`, of course)?

Comment: Thank you for the many attempts at deciphering my sql.  I'll try to be more verbose as none of the above worked as expected.

I have a status column that holds many values:  requested, deleted, appointment, completed, shipping, and several more.

Any database field update will also trigger an NOW() update to the update_datetime which is stored as a MySQL datetime type( 2013-04-11 12:10:20 ).

Comment: My goal is to display all requests except the ones that have been deleted or the requests that have been given the 'complete' status and have existed with no changes for the last 7 days.  After 7 days of holding the 'complete' status I wish for the requests to 'fall off' the view.

Later if I go back into the admin view and change something I would like the request to reappear in the customer view.

Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE
    status <> 'deleted'
AND (
        (update_datetime < unix_timestamp( now() - interval 7 day ) AND status = 'completed')
    OR  (update_datetime >= unix_timestamp( now() - interval 7 day ))
)
```

If the `update_datetime` is a `DATETIME` column, use this instead:

```
WHERE
    status <> 'deleted'
AND (
        (update_datetime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day) AND status = 'completed')
    OR  (update_datetime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day))
)
```

Comment: Got it to work with a minor adjustment to your response:
`
WHERE
   status <> 'deleted'
AND (
        (update_datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 day) AND status = 'completed')
    OR 
        (
          status <> 'completed'
        ) 
)`

Comment: Actually it is not what you said in the description of your problem, but I guess the most important is that you got it working the way you wish!

Comment: Too right you are... I'm sorry for the confusion.  You did answer exactly as I originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
WHERE
    (status <> 'deleted'
 OR status <> 'completed')
AND update_datetime < unix_timestamp( now() - interval 7 day )
```

it is equal to

```
WHERE
    (not status in ('deleted', 'completed'))
AND update_datetime < unix_timestamp( now() - interval 7 day )
```

Comment: Thank you for the many attempts at deciphering my sql.  I'll try to be more verbose as none of the above worked as expected.